# A fibration is a map which has the right lifting property with respect to injections that are weak equivalences

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, motivic-homotopy

As mentioned in [Motivic Homotopy Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-45897-5), an alternative criterion for $X\rightarrow Y$ to be a fibration is that the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>>> X;\\
@VV{i}V @VVV \\
B @>>> Y;
\end{CD}
$$
has the right extension property ($\exists B \rightarrow X$ making the diagram commute) for $i$ being an injection and weak equivalence.

Why is that true?

I have known that a Kan complex can be described as satisfying the right extension property for anodyne extensions. Is a weak equivalence a anodyne extension?

Comment: A map is not a Kan complex, you probably mean Kan fibration. It's a very classical result. Simplicial sets form a model category with Kan fibration and injections as cofibrations.

Comment: Are you working in the category of simplicial sets, with the usual ("Kan-Quillen") model structure, where a cofibration is an injection, and a fibrant object is a Kan complex?

Comment: @TimCampion Yes.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Any reference?

Comment: Your question is equivalent to asking why the anodyne extensions are precisely the injective weak equivalences. The fact that these two coincide follows from the statement that the cofibrations, fibrations, and weak equivalences on sSet form a model structure. The proof will depend on precisely how the definitions are set up -- various approaches are possible -- depending on the definitions, this statement is perhaps the heart of the proof that the model structure exists. You can read about this in Quillen's _Homotopical Algebra_ or Goerss-Jardine's _Simplicial Homotopy Theory_ for example.

Comment: A shorter and more pedagogical reference, which is good at black-boxing some believable but technical statements in topology, is Dwyer-Spalinski's [Homotopy theories and model categories](https://math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/616-s16/DwyerSpalinski.pdf).

Comment: @xtchen any elementary book on simplicial sets.